# Related Products with same attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, product-relations

I am trying to do the same thing in Magento CE 1.9.1.0 . Basically I want to edit the related products block to show all products that have the same value for a specific attribute. Basically I have an attribute called family and when you view product abc which belongs to the attribute family 'Pepsi' I want to display all other products that have a value for the family attribute of 'pepsi'

So I am altering the file app/design/frontend/MY_THEME/default/template/catalog/product/list/related.phtml

The first thing I do in this file is get the value of the family attribute by doing the below

```
         //get the name of the family that the product being viewed is a part of
         $itemcollectionname = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('family');
```

I then tried using the code in the above post like so

```
         $rcollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
         ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) //add some attribtues to select
         ->addAttributeToFilter('family', array('eq'=>$itemcollectionname);//filter products with the same family
         Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($rcollection); //only active products
         Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($rcollection);//only visible products
        $rcollection->setPage(1,5);//limit to 5 products
        echo "$rcollection<br />";
```

Comment: My issue is no products are appearing at all. What I want to achieve is where the "related products" appear on the product detail page I want a listing of 5 products that have the same value for the attrabute named family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set in Attribute settings "Used in product listing" to Yes.

Then you can simple do:

Avoid double load the product, it is already loaded.

```
    //$itemcollectionname = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getAttributeText('family');
$itemcollectionname = $_product->getAttributeText('family');
```

Or load a new collection like:

```
$itemcollectionname = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach($itemcollectionname as $product){
   echo $product->getFamily();
   //OR
   echo $product->getAttributeText('family');
}
```

So if you want to filter by family you will need a value to filter by:

Example:

```
$itemcollectionname = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('family', 'Pants');

    foreach($itemcollectionname as $product){
       echo $product->getId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the id by label and then perform addField to filter on the collection

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$attr = $productModel->getResource()->getAttribute("manufacturer");
if ($attr->usesSource()) {

     $manufacturer_id = $attr->getSource()->getOptionId("Nike");
}

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$manufacturer_id);
```

**I hope this will help you.**